# How to change data-type of mysql field using PHP and check it was changed?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to change one field in my table from `int(4)` to `datetime` using a PHP query, then I need to check if it was successfully changed.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer, and i will share it in case somebody stuck in that part.

to change the datatype i used:

```
$query = "ALTER TABLE `Table_Name` CHANGE `Field-to-Change` `Field-to-Change` DATETIME NULL;";
```

it works for me, and to test it i used:

```
 $query = "SELECT `Field-to-Change` FROM `Table_Name`";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
    {            
         if($result = $conn->query($query))
         {
            // Get field information for all columns
            while ($column_info = $result->fetch_field())
            {
                echo $column_info->type;
            }
        }
    }
```

it shows 12 as the number of datetime.
hopefully i will be helping somebody.